Is it safe to insert unsanitized html into an unattached node?
I want to get the text content only of some HTML. I don't know if this html is clean. I can do this as follows:
export function getTextContent(html: string) {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = html;
  return el.textContent || "";
};

My question is whether this is safe. By safe I mean that:

Scripts included in the HTML don't run
Any inline stylesheets do not effect the document
No requests are made for any resources (image, css, etc..) included in the markup


It's quite easy to test this, however: 1. They shouldn't but you're at the mercy of the browsers security implementation if you don't sanitise the content yourself (which you really should be). 2. They won't. 3. Resource requests will still be made. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2csphfbo/ - check the network traffic and console.

Assigning to innerHTML doesn't execute script elements, but inline event handlers can still be problematic. <img src="..." onload="..." onerror="..."> will execute either the load or the error handler, depending on whether requesting the image source succeeded or not.

But I guess you could clamp down on that - and the loading of external resources to begin with - if you executed this in a context, where you forbid all that stuff via a restrictive Content-Security-Policy? You will probably not be able to be that restrictive with the CSP for your actual page, but maybe you could do this within the context of an iframe, that has a much more restrictive CSP applied than the main document ...?
